# How do I map a local path to a drive letter in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, drive-letter

I am coding on something and want to map `\cygwin\home\bob\code\` to `U:` drive letter. When I try to map it using `net use C:\cygwin\home\bob\code\ U: /P:yes` , but it gave the following error:

```
System error 67 has occurred
The network name cannot be found
```

But it's not actually a network path I'm trying to map. How do I do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If it is only local what you need, try `subst`.

```
subst u: C:\cygwin\home\bob\code\
```

Comment: I got problems if I had a trailing backslash - if it doesn't work try it without. Then punch the screen. Then correct your sprelling.

Comment: It it normal that those virtual drives do not show-up in the Windows Explorer (Win10 1803)?

Answer (score 4):

Use [vSubst](http://home.datacomm.ch/t.bigler/). It is like the `subst` command line tool, but it has a UI and is persistent.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

When you map drives they must be mapped to a SHARED network folder. You are trying to map to a local path, it won't work. Instead try sharing the Code folder then use this:

> `net use u: \\yourpcname\code /p:yes`

Comment: This does what I want, but is there a way to "share" folder without anyone on another computer able to view it? In case I need to know that later.

Comment: nvm, see Roald's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this across bootup is to put it in the registry. Open *regedit.exe* by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and typing *regedit* then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click OK. Navigate to
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Control \ Session Manager \ DOS Devices`

Add a new string that is a **REG_SZ** value.
Name it **X:** where X is your drive letter
The value should be the path you want mapped to that drive letter, in this form:

`\DosDevices\C:\Folder\Example`

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.