# Can I show a folder as a drive?

Tags: windows-7, ntfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I map a local path to a drive letter in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/300098/how-do-i-map-a-local-path-to-a-drive-letter-in-windows-7)

I have a folder called "GAMES" on my `D:` drive. Is it possible, in ntfs, to treat that folder as a separate drive ?

I know that the opposite is possible (mounting a drive in a ntfs folder).