# Is it possible to change the location of Photoshop's scratch disk file?

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop

By default, scratch disks feature use "root directory" of selected partition/disk. For example:

```
X:\Photoshop Temp1664856906880
```

As I understand, these scratch disk files should be deleted after photoshop is closed, but this is not my case. Now I can see another two files present.

My question is, whether is it possible to change location of these files to some folder. E.g:

```
X:\scratch\Photoshop Temp1664856906880
```

In Photoshop CS6 there is no advanced settings under `Edit > Preferences > Performance...` where I could specify the path.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/300098/how-do-i-map-a-local-path-to-a-drive-letter-in-windows-7 is possible, but there have been minor issues at times with mapped stuff and windows.

Comment: Can you use an NTFS junction? Create one that points the scratch directory to any other drive and folder you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be keeping scratch files of recently opened documents.

It is definitely preferable to not have Photoshop using your boot drive as a scratch disk anyway, but you cannot specify any sub-folder, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. C drive was a bad example.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to control the location of the temporary files beyond which disks they will exist on.

> 1. Click **Edit** select to **Preferences**, and then click **Performance**.
> 2. Select the check box next to the scratch disk you want to use or clear the check box to remove it.

[Source](http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1915790&seqNum=11)

I couldn't find a screenshot of the Windows version, the instructions are the same, since the physical location on the drive can't be changed on both OS X and Windows.

Photoshop's inability to delete the files are likely connected user's permissions.  The solution to your problem is to use a different disk other then your system disk.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Newer Versions You can Hold `[CTRL]+[ALT]` keys When click to start Photoshop and then see windows to set scratch disk.

[Screen Capture of setting Scratch Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNH2a.jpg)